# How can I view IBM Watson Assistant conversation logs in my ASP.net application?

Tags: asp.net, node.js, ibm-watson

I understand that there is an API... but how do I implement it? I have a working node.js application but now I have to bring it over to asp.net. I think working from scratch on my asp.net web app is the best option now but I do not know how to start.

Comment: This is question is possibly too broad for stack overflow as there would be many ways to tackle this problem. I recommend to start by writing some code and then update your question if/when you encounter a problem you can't solve yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that knowing the exact issues you run into will help us give a better answer, but to get you started here is the .net sdk
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk
and the standard api reference with examples
https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs/assistant